# What is the extra property of this sheaf?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I have a particular mathematical structure, and I think it would be enlightening to try to place it in a categorical context.

The structure is a sheaf on a topological space, and the extra property is that not only can we patch together data from overlapping open sets, we can also do it sometimes when the open sets are *not* overlapping.

For example, I can take the data assigned to the open intervals $(r,s)$ and $(s,t)$ and combine them to recover uniquely the data assigned to the interval $(r,t)$.  In one dimension this all seems quite simple, but in higher dimensions the class of disjoint sets that you can patch together can be quite complicated.

I suppose in more categorical language we would say that the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ satisfies $\mathcal{F}((r,s) \cup (s,t))$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathcal{F}((r,t))$.

Is this kind of thing a known specialisation of a sheaf?  A sheaf on something other than a topological space?  A different sheaf-like object?  I'm trying to work out what's the ``morally correct'' framework in which to study these objects that I have.

Answer (score 7):

This seems like a perfectly reasonable sheaf, just not on the normal site associated to the topological space.  When we look at the site associated to a topological space $X$ we take the poset of open subsets of $X$ under inclusion.  To define the topology, we say that $\{U_i \rightarrow U\}_{i\in I}$ is a covering family if $\bigcup_{i\in I} U_i = U$.  If instead we say that $\{U_i\rightarrow U\}_{i\in I}$ is a covering family if $\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$ is dense in $U$ you'll get the site you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

To amplify Inna's answer, your sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ is even a sheaf for the [Lawvere–Tierney topology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere-Tierney+topology) on $\mathrm{Sh}(X)$ given by the [double-negation modality](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+negation). In other words, your sheaf is the pushforward of some sheaf along the embedding $X^{\neg\neg} \hookrightarrow X$, where $X^{\neg\neg}$ is the *smallest dense [sublocale](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale)* of $X$. (Recall that usually, there is no smallest dense sub_space_.)

So, the answer to your question "A sheaf on something other than a topological space?" is *yes*. It's a sheaf on a certain sublocale of your topological space.

I can provide details if wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Such a sheaf is certainly not finitely generated, at least over $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathcal{F}(I_1 \cup I_2) \cong \mathcal{F}(I_1) \oplus \mathcal{F}(I_2)$, we can split up an interval, say $(0,1)$ into $(0,1/2), (1/2, 1)$ and continually subdivide this up; as $\mathcal{F}(I) \cong \mathcal{F}(J)$ for any bounded open intervals, we necessarily have
$$
\mathcal{F}(I) \cong \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{F}(I).
$$

It seems to me that such sheaves would be very badly behaved, unless they are trivial.

Comment: In one dimension the condition just means that removing one point doesn't change the sections. For example $U\mapsto L^p(U)$ seems to have this property, and it's hard to call $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ "badly behaved"...

Comment: Well, those aren't finitely generated...

Point taken though. Not all such sheaves are horrible beasts.

Comment: @Simon: yes my sheaves have this property.  In fact one way of seeing these sheaves is that each $\mathcal{F}(I)$ is a probability space, and then your observation is (roughly) that the distributions are infinitely divisible (classically these are Levy processes, i.e. Brownian motions etc.).


Comment: @TomChurch: Perhaps you should take $U\mapsto L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}(U)$ instead, otherwise it's not a sheaf: $\exp | _{-\infty , x}$ are in $L^p(-\infty , x)$, and $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of the $(-\infty , x)$ but $\exp$ is not in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @unknowngoogle: good point; you're right.